# Java: Eclipse Plugin create issue

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

Below is the plugin code that i have tried to reuse from an old code that i got my hands on.
The plugin just wont run properly.
I have copied the plugin part of the code.

Please help me trouble shoot the issue.

1. on running in Eclipse Helios [image: error on running the plugin] 

   **UPDATED new error image**
   [image: validation message for plugin]

   but i am using JDK 1.6
   **UPDATED new error image**
2. Once i was able to run the plugin in RAD in debug mode, but was not able to install it in rad as a plugin. Since the plugin jar that was created, was not detected in Eclipse or RAD on start up.

*the idea trying to achieve here* is to get the **<project folder location>** when user tries to call the plugin. and pass that as a parameter to a stand alone code.

**Activator.java**

```
public class Activator extends AbstractUIPlugin {

    // The plug-in ID
    public static final String PLUGIN_ID = "PluginName";

    // The shared instance
    private static Activator plugin;


    public Activator() {
        plugin = this;
    }


    public void start(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Loading the PluginName");
        super.start(context);
    }


    public void stop(BundleContext context) throws Exception {
        plugin = null;
        System.out.println("Exiting the PluginName");
        super.stop(context);
    }

    public static Activator getDefault() {
        return plugin;
    }


    public static ImageDescriptor getImageDescriptor(String path) {
        return imageDescriptorFromPlugin(PLUGIN_ID, path);
    }
}
```

**FindUnwantedJarAction.java**

```
import org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject;
import org.eclipse.jface.action.IAction;
import org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.MessageDialog;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ISelection;
import org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IStructuredSelection;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
import org.eclipse.ui.IObjectActionDelegate;
import org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchPart;


public class FindUnwantedJarAction implements IObjectActionDelegate {
    private IStructuredSelection selection;

    public void setActivePart(IAction arg0, IWorkbenchPart arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void run(IAction arg0) {
        IProject project = (IProject) selection.getFirstElement();
        String projName = project.getName();
        String projectLocation = project.getLocation().toString();

        //call another class with this parameter
    }

    public void selectionChanged(IAction arg0, ISelection paramSelection) {
        this.selection = (IStructuredSelection) paramSelection;
    }

}
```

**Plugin.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.2"?>
<plugin>

   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">
      <objectContribution
            objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IProject"
            adaptable="true"
            id="core.UnwantedJar">
         <menu
               label="Find Unwanted Jars"
               path="additions"
               id="FindUnJar.menu1">
            <separator
                  name="group1">
            </separator>
         </menu>
         <action
               label="Find!!!"
               class="core.marksman.action.FindUnwantedJarAction"
               menubarPath="FindUnJar.menu1/group1"
               enablesFor="1"
               id="CVSLocal.newAction">
         </action>
      </objectContribution>
   </extension>

</plugin>
```

Comment: Can you please specify the problem encountered. This is not a debugging site

Comment: Oops!!!. added the issue faced

Comment: Did you tried to add that jar as Plugin dependency, because the dialog box which you have shown,it seems its not able to find appropriate class & dnt forget to add activator class.Best way to do,create a template plugin project which is provided by Eclipse & then add your code.

Comment: @Eshika i have updated my error image. I had tried using plugin template, but still in process of trying to reduce the code- by removing unwanted plugin references, i was not able to get that done. since the template i used usually had lot of unwanted plugin dependencies

Comment: Eclipse has its own Java path are you sure that it is setup to use the correct JDK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also give your MANIFEST.MF for the full diagnosis, but the most probable cause is that you are running your RAD using a different JDK than the one your development Eclipse instance is running with (and it is earlier than your bundle target environment which is set to JavaSE-1.6 in your MANIFEST.MF).

That might be the reason you could successfully run the RAD in the Debug mode but not as a standalone application. Please look at the log of your RAD instance and see the "java.version=" value. It should be 1.6... or later.